# What are HTML5Report Format HTML5 features

Tags: html

Two questions:

I'm curious as to what are the features in this HTML5ReportFormat that is considered HTML5 other than the doctype?
https://github.com/ServiceStack/ServiceStack/wiki/HTML5ReportFormat

And why doesn't it work in IE? Can I make it work in IE?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> ... what are the features in this
>   HTML5ReportFormat that is considered
>   HTML5 other than the doctype?

Nothing, as far as I can see.

> ... why doesn't it work in IE?

In response to the request, the server returns an html file with a content type of text/html to Firefox and Chrome, but JSON data with an content type of application/json to IE. It's doing some kind of content negotiation, but getting it wrong as IE doesn't know what to do with the JSON data on its own.

> Can I make it work in IE?

Probably not.

Comment: so it's pretty crap as I thought.

Answer (score 0):

The [HTML5 Format](https://github.com/ServiceStack/ServiceStack/wiki/HTML5ReportFormat) now works in IE8 now but requires an internet connection to download JSON2.js.

If there is enough interest I may include a minified JSON2 embedded inside the document, but I'm kinda against adding overhead for everyone else because IE is so lame - I much prefer users stop hurting the Internet and upgrade their browsers, for the time being it works but requires an external ref to JSON2.js - which I don't envisage to be a practical limitation.

Can also view it in IE7 but has some rendering issues with the JSON viewer which I'm not motivated to fix for same reasons above.